# 'Invalid operands "Array" and "int" for "*" operator' in Godot

Tags: arrays, syntax-error, godot

I am new in Godot and I'm getting this error when  I made this array:

```
var RL = [' '] + [atlas_coord_0[5]] * 5 + [atlas_coord_0[3]] * 5 + [atlas_coord_0[1]] * 10 * 5 + [main_block] * 25 * 5 + [atlas_coord_0[2]] * 25
```

I don't know how to fix this. Thanks for all your help! P.S. Don't hate on me pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically multiplying arrays by ints I see two things that you could be trying to do.

If by multiplying the arrays you search to repeat the array such as

```
[value] * 2 = [value, value]
```

I'm sorry to tell that a quick search revealed that there's no shortcut for this in gdscript (I'm not 100% sure please edit if I'm wrong). You can use a for loop.

If you just want to multiply the content of the array, well since it's a single value then you can move the closing square bracket after the multiplication.

Comment: Oh man, really was hoping to make this easy, but thanks for your help anyways